# How to test facebook like/share and opengraph on private server

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am trying to test on a private development server, and I can't use the linter to test why opengraph isn't being picked up on the share. I can set up an app id for the dev server and share the link, however none of the opengraph data is being picked up.

My code is:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" contant="IE=edge" />
<meta property="og:title" content="my title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="Park" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http:<%=cdnHost%>/my_domain" /> <!--ignoring parameters in url -->
<meta property="og:site_name" content="my site name"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="my description" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxxxxxxx"/>





<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxxxx";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<fb:like href="http:<%=cdnHost%>/my_directory"
    send="true" layout="button_count" width="100" show_faces="false">
</fb:like>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The og data is not getting picked up because the linter has no access to read that data.  You will need to **punch a hole thru your firewall** and setup DNS appropriately so Facebook can lint your URL.  Otherwise, you'll have to tell you QA team that it wont work behind the firewall and explain to them about Facebook's requirement that the URL be publicly accessible.

Comment: thanks DMCS - I appreciate the help. I'm assuming that the same reason why the "send" button does not work.

Comment: Correct, if Facebook can't lint it, then they generally don't like it (pun intended).

Comment: Any idea where I can find the info for the DNS setup?

Comment: Yes, your DNS setup is usually done at the place where you bought your domain from, unless you've changed your NameServers, then it will be at the place where you changed the default NameServers to.